# Change direction but not speed in simple game

Tags: android, vector

I'm fairly new to game programming and have taken a sample and am trying to do something in which I need a little help with some simple vector physics. I have a ball going across the screen in one direction at a fixed speed which is represented by a vector. I want to touch the screen somewhere else and have the ball change direction and go towards where I touched the screen at the same speed as it was going. I'm able to change direction easy but the speed changes based on the distance that I pressed from the current position. I've been trying to do some normalization, etc., with no success.

Here's the existing code that works but causes the ball to change speed when rendered. Hopefully this is enough info. Thanks much!!

```
            coord = graphic.getCoordinates();
            speed = graphic.getSpeed();

    // x and y are the newly touched coordinates and 
    // getTouchedX and getTouchedY are the current coordinates
            int diffX = x - coord.getTouchedX();
            int diffY = y - coord.getTouchedY();

            int amplitude = diffX / 10;
            graphic.getSpeed().setX(amplitude);

            amplitude = diffY / 10;
            graphic.getSpeed().setY(amplitude);
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'm able to change direction easy but the speed changes based on the
>   distance that I pressed from the current position. I've been trying to
>   do some normalization, etc., with no success.

I'm inclined to say you might've gotten the normalisation part wrong, because that should be the answer to your problem. Your code indeed changes the speed, since the difference between the current position and the touched position is simply scaled down by a factor 10. That means that the distance of the touch with respect to the current position influences the speed: the further away the touch, the faster the ball will move.

To prevent this from happening, normalize the x and y components to get a **unit vector**. Its characteristic is that its magnitude/length (the speed basically) is exactly '1'. You can think of it indicating what percentages of the total speed should go to the vertical and horizontal components.

```
int diffX = x - coord.getTouchedX();
int diffY = y - coord.getTouchedY();

double magnitude = Math.sqrt(diffX*diffX + diffY*diffY);

double amplitude = (double)diffX / magnitude;
graphic.getSpeed().setX(amplitude);

amplitude = (double)diffY / magnitude;
graphic.getSpeed().setY(amplitude);
```

Do note that I changed the amplitude to a `double`, as using an int value here will otherwise result in the component being truncated to either '0' or '1' (since the magnitude of a vector is always larger than or equal to its single components). Hence you might want to apply a scaling factor to get workable int values, although you'll lose accuracy in the process because of truncation. Depending on the scaling factor, this may or may not result in a notable speed different after touching the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is a great explanation and helped me to think it through, however, it doesn't quite solve the problem. A couple more things. The X and Y value of the speed are integers. Now it seems as if we are normalizing the new values rather than the old values. I was assuming that we want to normalize the old value then some how apply that to get the new speed. However, what we have right now always results in a amplitude of close to one, which is rounded off to zero since the values are integers. Thanks again. I might be able to take it from here but any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you read the last part of my answer, because I address the int/double en speed issues in there. In order to have the ball moving equally fast as before, multiply the normalized values by the current speed. I'm assuming the speed is given by `getSpeed()` - if not, just calculate it in the same manner as above (but don't normalize of course). Hope that helps!